# Include Asset into new Unity library

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now I'm preparing new Unity Asset for developers. The main idea is to download asset from Unity app store for free. This asset allows other developers to send diagnostic JSON files to backend API's. Because Unity has so many problems with serializing dictionaries I try to found best solution to create diagnostic JSON and I found existing Asset (Json.NET).

My question is: when I prepare a public package for Unity developers, should I include other assets to my library? If not - what other ways Unity developers prefer?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Keep assets as separate downloads as much as you can, then the developer can download only what they need.  Once you import an asset into Unity it can be very hard to figure out what you need and what you don't need if multiple assets were packaged together.  This takes up disk space, compile time and can be extremely confusing and messy especially when some of the assets have dependencies that break with the upgrade of another component or Unity itself.

As an aside my biggest gripe with Unity is that it doesn't seem like it is stable enough to make a production app on sometimes.  Too many nuances and bugs in each version and the number of versions is staggering.